# Console application with progress indication and multiple places like ffmpeg

Tags: .net, .net-core, terminal, console, console-application

I writing a console application in .NET that should update progress indicators in a way many nicer command line tools do. I even want to update multiple such indicators at different places in a tree structure.

I know about [gui.cs](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs/issues) that would do the heavy lifting here, especially since it already implements tree structures, but there's some problem: It seems to be geared only at full-screen curses-style apps, and I want ultimately a command-line tool that only takes up as much height as required and leaves its output after terminating.

What are my best options here?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do multiline "smart" output, but a simple loop printing `"\r  {}% done. "` worked for me (the trick is in the carriage return symbol).